# Quiz game using firebase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I try to make quiz game with firebase in unity 3d.

The problem is, when i try to get data by id in child level, all data in level key entered in 1 scene. I want the data get by id one by one. what should i change in my code?

This is my code to get data from firebase:

```
private IEnumerator LoadQuestionData(string level)
{
    var DBTask = DBreference.Child("questions").OrderByChild("level").GetValueAsync();

    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

    if (DBTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
    }
    else
    {
        // Data has been retrieved
        DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;

        // Destroy any existing question elements
        foreach (Transform child in questionuserContent.transform)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        List<DataSnapshot> questionSnapshots = new List<DataSnapshot>();

        // Loop through each level
        foreach (DataSnapshot childLevelSnapshot in snapshot.Children.Reverse<DataSnapshot>())
        {
            // Loop through each question of the level
            foreach (DataSnapshot childSnapshot in childLevelSnapshot.Children.Reverse<DataSnapshot>())
            {
                questionSnapshots.Add(childSnapshot);
            }
        }

        // Shuffle the question snapshots using Fisher-Yates algorithm
        int n = questionSnapshots.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
           int k = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n + 1);
            DataSnapshot temp = questionSnapshots[k];
            questionSnapshots[k] = questionSnapshots[n];
            questionSnapshots[n] = temp;
        }

        int questionCount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < questionCount; i++)
        {
            DataSnapshot questionSnapshot = questionSnapshots[i];

            string questionId = questionSnapshot.Key;
            string question = questionSnapshot.Child("question").Value.ToString();
            string optiona = questionSnapshot.Child("optiona").Value.ToString();
            string optionb = questionSnapshot.Child("optionb").Value.ToString();
            string optionc = questionSnapshot.Child("optionc").Value.ToString();
            string optiond = questionSnapshot.Child("optiond").Value.ToString();
            string correctAnswer = questionSnapshot.Child("correctAnswer").Value.ToString();
            int score = int.Parse(questionSnapshot.Child("score").Value.ToString());

            string userAnswer = "user's answer";
            // Calculate score based on correct answer
            if (CheckAnswer(userAnswer, correctAnswer))
            {
                // Increase the total score
                totalScore += score;
            }

            // Instantiate elemen pertanyaan baru
            GameObject questionObj = Instantiate(questionuserElement, questionuserContent);
            // Setel nilai-nilai elemen pertanyaan
            questionObj.GetComponent<UserQuestionElement>().UserQuestionData(questionId, level, question, optiona, optionb, optionc, optiond, correctAnswer, score);
        
        }

        // Save the total score automatically
        SaveScore(totalScore);

        // Tampilkan layar admin dengan tabel pertanyaan
        UIManager.instance.EasyUIScreen();
    }
}
```

this is my structur in firebase

[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2fwc.png)

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: how can i add JSON text in this question sir?

Comment: Just add the JSON as a codeblock

Comment: Again: please don't add the JSON (or other textual content) as a screenshot. Instead add it as text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.